# I have this issue java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: android, libgdx

The project run fine if I run Descktop version but when I run the android version  crush with FALTAL EXCEPTION GLTHREAD java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label.

```
private void buildElements()
{
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------
    // Background.
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------
    //Image image = new Image(logo, Scaling.none);
    //image.width = width;
    //image.height = height;

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------
    // Labels
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------

    try{

        titleLabel =new Label("DEMO", "large-font", Color.YELLOW, skin);

        poweredByLabel =new Label("DEMO", "large-font", Color.YELLOW, skin);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(TAG + " ( ) " + e.getMessage());
    }

    table.pack();

    addActor(titleLabel );
}
```

Seems to be when it comes to the line titleLabel.... but why?

please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the folder where your Label jar is. There might be two different versions of the same or you might be using an older version that does not contain the method.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify if the versions of Jar are matching up. There is a older version in your path that is causing the issue.