# libGdx constructor crashing parameter: Color

Tags: parameters, colors, crash, libgdx

I've created a class with an attribute `Color`.

```
public class CurveParticle {
    private Circle c;
    private boolean collidable;
    private Color color;

    public CurveParticle(Circle c, boolean coll){
        this.c = c;
        this.collidable = coll;
    }
    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = new Color(color);
    }       
}
```

The Color is from import `com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color`.

Whenever I try to set the color with a setter method, or even pass in the color to the constructor(I've removed the parameter in this example), it gives me this kind of an exception:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.me.Kurve.CurveParticle.setColor(Lcom/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Color;)V
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.me.Kurve.CurveParticle.setColor(Lcom/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Color;)V
    at com.me.Kurve.Kurve.show(Kurve.java:67)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:62)
    at com.me.Screens.EnterGame.create(EnterGame.java:12)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:136)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
```

Should I instead of that passing a float array or something. It's really weird because without the color parameter everything worked fine. I don't think I'm to blame here am I?

Comment: check your imports to make sure you are using com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color and not java.awt.Color

Comment: I've checked that before I posted this, they all seem alright, any other suggestions?

Comment: How are you compiling it? is this a deployed application? what classpath are you specifying? what is your directory structure? (Nothing is wrong with the code you are showing so it must be a configuration issue).

Comment: I guess it is a configuration issue, because I tried it with another project and it seemed to work. I will rebuild everything now, hoping for success. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the other instances that I can find of this error have to do with out-of-sync or old jars. Example: [I have this issue java.lang.NoSuchMethodError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303292/i-have-this-issue-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror)

The Java documentation supports this:

> Thrown if an application tries to call a specified method of a class (either static or instance), and that class no longer has a definition of that method.
>   Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed.

Do you have the latest release of libgdx? You might want to try downloading the newest and replacing what you have.

Also, specifically check for duplicate versions in your project setup: [Interpreting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945862/interpreting-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-message)

Did you build your project manually, or use the project setup helper tool?

Comment: Ok I will update libGdx, but I don't understand what you mean by checking for duplicate versions? I've used the project setup helper tool.

Comment: Thanks for pointers guys, I've basicly just set all up from the start and it works now, probably some old configurations like you said Jeremy. Thanks again!!!